# Why does `requestAirdrop` fail on my local validator?

Tags: web3.js, airdrop

After `requestAirdrop`, I am confirming the transaction with `confirmTransaction`, but I am having trouble executing the airdrop. The version of `@solana/web3.js` is 1.75.0(latest).

I am using the following procedure for airdrop.

```
// 1. Create connection.
const connection = new Connection(network, "confirmed");

// 2. Call `requestAirdrop`
const signature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
  publicKey,
  1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
);

// 3. Get latest blockHash
const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

// 4. Call confirmTransaction
await connection.confirmTransaction(
  {
    signature,
    blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
  },
  "confirmed",
);
```

**[Result]**

No matter how long I wait, the `confirmTransaction` function does not return when using localnode (http://127.0.0.1:8899).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the script. Everyone is facing issue while claiming airdrop on devnet which might be due to high abuse or wallet drain.

Comment: @0xShuk
Thank you for confirming and reply that there is nothing wrong with my code. But I don't know why localnode(solana-test-validator) doesn't return any response.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my side, so perhaps some internal ports aren't properly exposed